# How do I hide the Control Panel icon COMPLETELY from a Windows Client using Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, control-panel, hide

Basically what the title says... I don't only want the items to be gone from the control panel. I also want the control panel icon gone.

Comment: What are you trying to do by preventing the use of the control panel?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Your question makes no mention of the fact your in a AD domain